# Linear independent vectors multiplied by a matrix.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, systems-of-equations, matrix-rank

My question is deceptively simple. Let $v_1, \dots, v_m \in \mathbb{R}^n$ be a set of vectors linearly independent. If we multiply them by a matrix A, such that the vectors $Av_1, \dots, Av_m$ are linearly dependent, which of the following sentences is true and why or why not.

- rank($A$) < m.
- rank($A$) < n.

I am really stuck with this. I've made some calculations like, if $Av_1, \dots, Av_m$ are linearly dependent, then

$\lambda_1(Av_1) + \dots + \lambda_m(Av_m) = 0$

has more than one solution. Rewriting the last expression i concluded that

$A(\lambda_1 v_1 + \dots + \lambda_m v_m) = 0$

And here I got stuck.

Comment: how many columns does $A$ have?  Do you know what rank-nullity is?  Why would that be useful here?

Comment: I don't know what it is

Comment: The number of columns of A must be n. Otherwise, $Av_i$ doesn't make sense. Think A as a linear map from $\mathbb{R}^n$ to some vector space. From what you have written, it is clear that dim Null(A) >0. Thus, rank(A)=dim Range(A) <n for sure.